# undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass on Create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I' am trying to create a program with a header and details and got this error on the development. My Goal is to create a header and then save its id in the details table for the AREL.
Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk6E0.png)
NoMethodError in EcnDetails#create 
Showing C:/Ruby24-x64/code/ECN/app/views/ecn_details/new.html.erb where line #1 raised: 
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #1):

Error Details:

```
Rails.root: C:/Ruby24-x64/code/ECN
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace 
app/views/ecn_details/new.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_ecn_details_new_html_erb__19924186_93249280'
app/controllers/ecn_details_controller.rb:33:in `create'
Request
Parameters:
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8WPqjsZJzmqnyOVvuQtKLMhas503UZqiB8jEUzvthtoCCa8k9Z7Mr+iX6y/Yt3Ig5lvNO4qTO5bbtKTsZZs5sw==",
 "ecn_detail"=>
  {"ecn_headers_id"=>"1",
   "old_parts_itemcode"=>"OD9008400A",
   "old_parts_partname"=>"FILTER BKT",
   "old_parts_instruction"=>"BUY",
   "new_parts_itemcode"=>"0EU026000",
   "new_parts_partname"=>"FILTER BASE BKT",
   "new_parts_instruction"=>"NO CHANGE UNTIL STOCKS DEPLETED",
   "remarks"=>"-",
   "bom"=>"MASTER BOM AS IS, 10-11-17",
   "sales"=>"-",
   "scm"=>"-",
   "overall_status"=>"WAITING FOR SCM UPDATE"},
 "commit"=>"Create Details",
```

View Code:

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", ecn_details_path(:ecn_headers_id => @header.id), :class => 'back-link') %>

   <div class="ecn_details new">   <h2>Create ECN Details</h2>

   <%= form_for(@detail, :url => ecn_details_path(:ecn_headers_id => @header.id)) do |f| %>
```

Controller Code:

```
class EcnDetailsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_header, :only => [:index, :new]    

  def index
    #@details = @header.details.sorted
    @details = EcnDetail.where(:ecn_headers_id => @header.id).sorted
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => handle_record_not_found
    #@page_title = "Details"
  end

  def show
    @details = EcnDetail.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    @detail = EcnDetail.new(:ecn_headers_id => @header.id)
  end

  def create 
    @detail = EcnDetail.new(detail_params)
    if @detail.save 
      flash[:notice] = "ECN Details created successfully."
      redirect_to(ecn_details_path(:ecn_headers_id => @header.id))
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error in creating ECN Details."
      render('new')
    end
  end

  def edit
    @details = EcnDetail.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @details = EcnDetail.find(params[:id])
    if @details.update_attributes(details_params)
     # if save succeeds
      flash[:notice] = "ECN Details updated successfully."
      redirect_to(ecn_details_path(@detail, :ecn_header_id => @header.id))
    else
      # if save fails
      flash[:error] = "Failed to update ECN Details"
      render('edit')
    end
  end

  def delete
    @details = EcnDetail.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @detail = Detail.find(params[:id])
    @page.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "ECN Details destroyed successfully."
    redirect_to(details_path(:ecn_header_id => @header.id))
  end

  private
  def detail_params
    params.require(:ecn_detail).permit(:ecn_headers_id,:old_parts_itemcode,
    :old_parts_partname, :old_parts_instruction, :new_parts_itemcode,
    :new_parts_partname, :new_parts_instruction, :remarks, :bom, :sales,
    :scm, :overall_status)
  end

  def find_header
    @header = EcnHeader.find(params[:ecn_headers_id])
  end

  def find_headers
    @header = EcnHeader.sorted
  end

  def handle_record_not_found
    yield
    redirect_to ecn_details_path, :flash => { :notice => "No Record found."}
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", ecn_details_path(:ecn_headers_id =>
@header.id), :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="ecn_details new">   
<h2>Create ECN Details</h2>
<%= form_for(@detail, :url => ecn_details_path(:ecn_headers_id =>  @header.id)) do |f| %>
    <%= render(:partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f})%>
    <div class="form-buttons">
        <%= f.submit("Create Details") %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

-Partial View

```
<%= error_messages_for(f.object) %>

<table summary="ECN Details form fields">
   <tr>
   <%= f.hidden_field(:ecn_headers_id)%>
     <th>OLD ITEM CODE</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field(:old_parts_itemcode) %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>OLD PART NAME</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field(:old_parts_partname) %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>INSTRUCTION</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field(:old_parts_instruction) %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>NEW ITEM CODE</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field(:new_parts_itemcode) %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>NEW PART NAME</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field(:new_parts_partname) %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>INSTRUCTION</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field(:new_parts_instruction) %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>REMARKS</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field(:remarks) %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>BOM</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field(:bom) %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>SALES</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field(:sales) %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>SCM</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field(:scm) %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>STATUS</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field(:overall_status) %></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you getting this error while saving the **Ecn Details** or while directing to the `new` action

Answer (score 2):

The error message "undefined method for nil:NilClass" means you are trying to call a method on something that you don't expect to be nil but is.  If you look at like #1 of `new.html.erb` it says: `@header.id` so the error message is telling you that `@header` is `nil` or not being set.

The way you wrote your create action, if it's unable to save the `EcnDetail` it renders the new view.  When you tell rails to render a different view, it doesn't run the controller code, it just renders the erb file.

From the looks of the code from the controller that you posted there is somewhere else that you are setting `@header` for the new action.  That isn't being set in the create action, so when the creation fails `@header` is unset and rails treats it as `nil`

If you need further help, please post your entire controller code.

Comment: thanks for your immediate response i already updated my controller above.

Comment: hi @Josh i' m still checking '@header' but as i can see it throws correctly the data in my detail action new base from the generated sql query and  '@header' id is present in my URL parameter as ecn_headers_id. can you explain more details how i can debug this error. thanks